# Фото из параметра thumbnailphoto в подпись outlook

Tags: visual-basic, active-directory, outlook

Всем привет!
Переделываю скрипт добавления подписи в outlook, хочу сделать так, чтобы фото, которое находится в атрибуте "thumbnailphoto" добавлялась в подпись. Есть секция в скрипте "strLogo = objuser.thumbnailPhoto" она "должна" добавить фото, но вместо фото добавляется строка в шестнадцатеричном формате из атрибута в AD. Как я понял, для начала нужно преобразовать значение, но как это сделать я не знаю. Может кто сталкивался с подобной задачей?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim objFSO, thumbnailphoto, bmpfile, rs, ByteArray2Text

thumbnailphoto = objUser.thumbnailphoto

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Fields.Append "temp", 201, LenB(thumbnailphoto)
rs.Open
rs.AddNew
rs("temp").AppendChunk thumbnailphoto
rs.Update
ByteArray2Text = rs("temp")
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set bmpFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("c:\Bmp\photo.bmp", True)
bmpFile.Write(ByteArray2Text)
bmpFile.Close
```

Comment: Сохраняет файл bmp с нулевым весом, так и должно?